# MySQL JOIN WITH CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query,

```
SELECT
table1.*,
CASE 1
WHEN 1 THEN table2.t2
WHEN 2 THEN table3.t3
END AS t_value

FROM table1

CASE 1
WHEN 1 THEN LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHEN 2 THEN LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.table1_id
END
```

I have 3 different tables, table1 is the base table and i need to join one of other table (which is decided with a case)

Comment: Would it be easier to have 2 SELECTs and UNION the 2 result sets together?

Comment: No, unioning the result may not be what he is looking for but I see a use of dynamic  query here. That is store your table name to join in variable based on condition and use that variable while joining.

Comment: You are joining `table1` to `table1`, so when condition 1 is true you have: `SELECT table1.*, table2.t2 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table1 table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id`. So it looks like you are joining `table1` with an alias of either `table2` or `table3`. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: You surely do not have `CASE 1`. What is the case expression, does it depend on the table1's data or is it outside of it?

Comment: How about 2 OUTER JOINs and pick and choose what you want from either; or do they have to be inner joins? Is there only 1 field from each table required - so you could use a sub-select field instead of joins?

Answer (score 0):

You may try a dynamic query something like below (not exact one but a sample)

```
declare @tablename varchar(30)
declare @query varchar(500)

if(condition = 1)
set @tablename = table2.t2
else 
set @tablename = table3.t3

set @query = 'SELECT
table1.*
FROM table1
join'

set @query = concat(@query,@tablename)

sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Actually the condition is not predefined,it will be according to the current row (eg, "table1.status = 0").

Answer (score 0):

If there's only 1 field to consider, something like this (I'm not a MySQL user)? :

```
SELECT
  table1.*,
  CASE (row_condition)
   WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT table2.t2 FROM table1 t1
                  LEFT JOIN table2 ON t1.id = table2.table1_id)
   WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT table3.t3 FROM table1 t1
                  LEFT JOIN table3 ON t1.id = table3.table1_id)
  END AS t_value
FROM table1
```

You may have to rework the JOINS, consider whether it returns 1 row or more (and so use LIMIT 1 at the end of each sub-select), 'COALESCE' in the case of NULLs, etc.